# Set state if any of the value in array exists

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have a listener that sets the state if the value exists. It previously worked fine when I just had one value like so.

```
subscribe('feature-settings-updated', (evt, enabledFeatures) => {
                setIsEnabled(enabledFeatures.includes('showEmployeesReport'));
        });
```

Now I have a second value and rather than duplicating the code I want to do it so that it takes an array and if either one of the value exists then set it to true. Following is my attempt but it only enables it for just the one. Any ideas?

```
const features = ['showEmployeesReport', 'showCustomersReport'];
            subscribe('feature-settings-updated', (evt, enabledFeatures) => {
                setIsEnabled(
                    features.some(exp => enabledFeatures.includes(exp))
                );
            });
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be features.some.. instead of experiments?

Comment: yes.. sorry typo

Comment: Sorry to insist, but you still have enabledFeatures.some instead of features

Comment: can you console.log(enabledFeatures) inside the event handler?

Comment: Do you want to call `setIsEnabled` with `true` if any of the features is enabled? (which doesn't quite make sense to me)

Comment: @BenAston yes.. and why is that?

Comment: `features.some(exp => enabledFeatures.includes(exp))` will enumerate `features` and return `true` as soon as it finds _the first_ feature that also exists inside `enabledFeatures`. Is that what you want? In effect it tells you "are _any_ features enabled?" This value is then passed to `setIsEnabled`

Comment: What does "it only enables it for just the one" mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to reference the wrong variable (`experiments` instead of `features`):

```
const features = ['showEmployeesReport', 'showCustomersReport'];
subscribe('feature-settings-updated', (evt, enabledFeatures) => {
    setIsEnabled(
        features.some(feature => enabledFeatures.includes(feature))
    );
});
```

Comment: sorry was a typo. I corrected it. Still have the issue